# How create dataframe with columns name from dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

from this code:

```
response=session.get(urllink) 
tabella=pd.read_json(response.content)
data=tabella["table"]
print(data)
```

I get this dictionary (or I think it is a dictionary), how could I create a dataframe with AAA,BBB,CCC as columns name and all the data ordered in columns?

````
0      {'AAA': '111', 'BBB': '111', 'CCC': '111',...
1      {'AAA': '222', 'BBB': '222', 'CCC': '222',...
2      {'AAA': '333', 'BBB': '333', 'CCC': '333',...
3      {'AAA': '444', 'BBB': '444', 'CCC': '444',...
4      {'AAA': '555', 'BBB': '555', 'CCC': '555',...
...
Name: table, Length: 200, dtype: object```
````

I tried with
`df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)`
but I get the same result as before

Comment: `tabella=pd.read_json(response.content, lines=True)` ?

Comment: The `data` object you get isn't a dictionary. It is a pandas Series object (tabella is a pandas DataFrame; when you do `tabella["table"]`, you get a column from that dataframe, which is a series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying `pd.Series` on the column:

```py
print(df["table"].apply(pd.Series))
```

Prints:

```
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0  111  111  111
1  222  222  222
2  333  333  333
3  444  444  444
4  555  555  555
```

Comment: Yes, is working great! I didnt know the pd.Series, thank you!!!

Comment: the real magic here is actually the `.apply()` method. the thing at the end of your question (`data`) is itself a `pd.Series`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df["table"].tolist())
```